# Make a new table in DB to extract data from an already existing large table

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am working on a database which has around 2 year data and has around 100 million rows and 30 columns with values of every 10 seconds of different parameters. I want to create a new table which will have average of these data containing only 1 row for each date of data. The database has around 100 000 rows for each date.
Table name is process
and primary key is id

How can I do it because whenever I search for something in this already existing table it takes a long time to find out the required output.

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? OR do you support both? Why both tags?

In PostgreSQL I'd use `CREATE TABLE AS` or (in 9.4) a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`

Comment: i am working on postgresql

Comment: is it possible to create a new table which will take the average of all the data(around 1 lakh rows) of a single date and put them in one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to create a new table which will take the average of all the data(around 1 lakh rows) of a single date and put them in one row

You want something like:

```
CREATE TABLE averages AS
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', data_capture_timestamp_column) AS day,
    avg(col1) AS col1_avg,
    avg(col2) AS col2_avg,
    ...
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1;
```

The `GROUP BY 1` says to `GROUP` the data by the first `SELECT` argument, which in this case is the date. An expression index on `my_table( date_trunc('day', data_capture_timestamp_column))` is recommended.

Comment: its not working. May be i have not used your solution properly.

Comment: i hv tried this query in pgadmin it is showing error in or nearby from

Comment: select date_trunc('day',data_capture_timestsamptz_column) as day,
avg (col1) AS col1_avg,
avg(col2) AS col2_avg,
from processes
group by 1;

Comment: i have changed that also it is giving me the output if i don't use this avg() function.    this is the code i have actually tried :  SELECT  date_trunc('day', processtime) AS day,
avg(power) AS power_avg,
avg(speed) AS speed_avg,
      
FROM   processes,

GROUP  BY 1;                                                          it is giving error as       ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 5: FROM   processes,
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 105

Comment: @user3732694 I think you need to go through in introductory tutorial on SQL. Start here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html . You have a comma before the `FROM`. Hence the syntax error saying "near `FROM`".

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. Sorry to annoy you by my silly mistake